# Java Files : Trying to append the result to an already existing file using FileWriter

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I am trying to append the result to an already existing file using a FileWriter chained with BufferedReader.

```
String result = "";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
result = sb.toString(); 
//After some processing, storing the result in the 'result' variable
System.out.println(result);
// outputting the result on the command prompt
// It is correctly showing me the result on the command prompt
try
{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Demo/SPCC/Assembly1.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out.write(result);
// But, the above code fragment is not appending the result to the file
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");            
}
// Thank you so much!
```

Comment: You're never closing the writer, so all the data is just in the buffer. Use try-with-resources statements instead. Not adding this as an answer, as this is a duplicate of many other questions, but I don't have time to find them right now.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm

Comment: @Os. I am trying to append the result to the file and the above code is not able to do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Will try closing the writer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you so much. It worked. :)